# How Do I Store A PHP Variable In JS For Use With jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, javascript

I'm wondering where I would put code to take a variable from PHP (used in numbering classes) and store it in a variable that jQuery can access?

Here is an example:

```
$(".object1-22").hover(function(e){
    $(".object2-22").show();
}, function(e) {
    $(".object2-22").hide();
});
```

So in my code, I have two objects. When you hover over the 22nd instance of object1, I want it to *only* display the 22nd instance of object2.

How could I perform this task?

Comment: See [`wp_localize_script`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create IDs for your objects (*"22nd instance of object2"*), use HTML IDs, not CSS classes.

I guess you want the same behavior for *all* the objects, so do not write separate event handlers for each of them. Use a common CSS class (`object1` and `object2`) and individual IDs (`object1-22`, `object2-22`)

Consider

```
$(".object1").hover(function(e){
    $('#' + this.id.replace(/object1-/, 'object2-').show();
}, function(e) {
    $('#' + this.id.replace(/object1-/, 'object2-').hide();
});
```

You could even link the related elements beforehand.

```
$(".object1")
.each(function () {
    this.partner = $(this.id.replace(/^object1-/, 'object2-')[0];
})
.hover(function () {
    $(this.partner).show();
}, function () {
    $(this.partner).hide();
});
```

That being said, this is a question for StackOverflow, unfortunately I do not have enough rep here to flag it accordingly.

Comment: I apologize for posting it in the wrong spot. I assumed it would be good here since I searched jQuery on SE and this was the first result. I'll repost it elsewhere.

Comment: @Aerodynamo never mind re-posting, this question will get migrated if it finds the interest of some high-rep users here. (Besides, maybe it's more related to WP than I realize, I'm only here by accident.)

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just echo the php variable out in to the javascript? Or am I misunderstanding your question?

```
jsVar = <?php echo $phpVar; ?>
```